# C programming: How to sort an array in an ascending order

Tags: c

```
for (c = 0; c < 26; c++) {
    for (d = c + 1; d < 26; d++) {
        if (count[c] > count[d]) {
            tem = count[c];
            count[c] = count[d];
            count[d] = tem;

            printf("%c: %d\n", c + 'a', count[c]);
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to sort an array in ascending order. I tried to get help from already answered questions, but they all did not work for me.

My code:

1. User inputs a lowercase characters
2. program prints out each character in ascending order
   (e.g. input: ggggllppp output: l-2 p-3 g-4)

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: You have `for (d=d+1; d<26; d++) {`; you should probably initialize `d` from `c` — `for (int d = c + 1; d < 26; d++) {`.

Comment: You need `counting-sort` on chars in the string & any sort on those counts. You need to preserve the indices, as of now you're mangling them & losing the `char-index`

Comment: Thank you. I edited that part, but I am still not getting the output I want.

Comment: You probably need two parts to the data — the character and the count for that character.  At the moment, you are just swapping counts, which moves the count to a different letter from what it represented originally.

Comment: Post code that shows how this code is called: a [mcve] and input used.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of a structure to store both `ASCII` value & count of a character in the string. Once you've all the counts, sort the structures based on the counts.

Alter the print statement to your liking.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int ascii;
    int count;
} azCount_t;


int cmp(const void *p, const void *q) {
    return (((azCount_t*)p)->count > ((azCount_t*)q)->count);
}

int main (void) {
    char str [] = "program prints out each character in ascending order (e.g. input: ggggllppp output: l-2 p-3 g-4)";
    int slen = strlen (str);
    azCount_t acs [256] = {0};
    // Initialising the structure with ascii codes
    for (int ci = 0; ci < 256; ++ci)
        acs [ci].ascii = ci;    //ascii index
    // counting the occurrences of chars in input string
    for (int si = 0; si < slen; )
        ++acs[(unsigned char)str[si++]].count;

    //sort based on count ascedning order
    qsort (acs, 256, sizeof(azCount_t), cmp);

    printf ("Character Counts in string:\n[%s]\n", str);
    for (int ai = 0; ai < 256; ++ai)
        if (acs[ai].count)
            printf ("[%c] - %d\n", acs[ai].ascii, acs[ai].count);

    printf ("\n");
    return 0;
}
```